# How to get two different gtm.timer based events to fire in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, timer, dom-events, google-tag-manager

I followed [these directions](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/auto-event-tracking-google-tag-manager/) to create a gtm.timer based event

However, I'd like to make a second – one to fire @ 10 seconds, and the next at 25 seconds

I created a secondary listener tag to fire at 25000ms instead of 10000ms, but not sure what to set the rule to on my new event tag to not trip over the first event, since they are both called `gtm.timer`

**Here is my first listener tag:**

```
Tag Name    : 10 seconds plus - Event Listener
Tag Type    : Timer Listener
Event Name: gtm.timer
Interval    : 10000
Limit:  1
Firing Rules
All pages   {{url}} matches RegEx .*
Advanced Settings
Priority when firing tags   0
Firing schedule At any time.
Only fired in published containers
```

**And my first event tag:**

```
Tag Name:   10 seconds plus - Non Bounce GA
Tag Type    : Universal Analytics
Tracking ID:    {{UA-ID}}
Enable Display Advertising Features 
Track Type:     Event
Event Category: Readers
Event Action:   10 seconds
Event Label 
Event Value 
Non-Interaction Hit:    False
Anonymize IP:   False
Firing Rules
10 second timer {{event}} contains gtm.timer
Advanced Settings
Priority when firing tags   0
Firing schedule At any time.
Only fired in published containers
```

**And here is my 2nd event listener:**

```
Tag Name:   25 second plus - Event Listener
Tag Type    : Timer Listener
Event Name: gtm.timer
Interval:   25000
Limit:  1
Firing Rules
All pages   {{url}} matches RegEx .*
Advanced Settings
Priority when firing tags   0
Firing schedule At any time.
Only fired in published containers:     False
```

...And this is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Is 25 seconds critical? If 30 seconds is sufficient, you could simply make the timer fire every 10 seconds for 3 iterations. Otherwise, you can set it to fire every 5 seconds for 5 iterations.

If you add the number of seconds or the iteration number to the data sent as part of the event, then you can filter on the reporting side. The advantage of this method is that you can change the filters after the fact or you can better track engagement on page content based on the number of events that fired per user.

If I read between the lines correctly, it appears that you're trying to counterbalance your bounce rate based on the length of time a user remains on the page. This is an interesting idea, but I'd be careful not to put too much weight on it because the usual measure of engagement requires the user to follow an additional call to action after landing on your site.

Comment: Thank you; I'll see what I can accomplish with this. For now I will upvote since this gives me a direction to try until I can report success – at which point (barring another solution) I'll accept it. PS - While it's related to bounces, I'm more interested lately in tracking 'readers' vs 'hoppers', whether they leave my site or not. I'm aware that this can also be done with scroll tracking, but that doesn't necessarily indicate that someone is reading by itself. :)